# CPU hashes faster than GPU?

Tags: c++, hash, opencl

I want to generate a random number, and hash that with `SHA256` on my GPU using `OpenCL` with [this](https://github.com/Fruneng/opencl_sha_al_im/tree/master/sha256) base code (instead of hashing those pre-given plain-texts, it hashes the random numbers).
I got all the hashing to work on my GPU, but there is one problem:
the amount of hashes done per second lowers when using OpenCL?

Yes, you heard that correctly, at the moment it's faster to use only the CPU over only using the GPU.
My GPU runs at only `~10%` while my CPU runs at `~100%`

My question is: how can this be possible and more importantly, how do I fix it?

This is the code I use for generating a `Pseudo-Random Number` (which doesn't change at all between the 2 runs):

```
long Miner::Rand() {
    std::mt19937 rng;
    // initialize the random number generator with time-dependent seed
    uint64_t timeSeed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::seed_seq ss{ uint32_t(timeSeed & 0xffffffff), uint32_t(timeSeed >> 32) };
    rng.seed(ss);
    // initialize a uniform distribution between 0 and 1
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0, 1);
    double rnd = unif(rng);
    return floor(99999999 * rnd);
}
```

Here is the code that calculates the hashrate for me:

```
void Miner::ticker() {
    SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);
    while (true) {
        Sleep(1000);
        HashesPerSecond = hashes;
        hashes = 0;
        PrintInfo();
    }
}
```

which gets called from here:

```
void Miner::Start() {
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point today = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(today);
    std::thread tickT(&Miner::ticker, this);
    PostHit();
    GetAPIBalance();
    while (true) {
        std::thread t[32]; //max 32
        hashFound = false;
        if (RequestNewBlock()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
                t[i] = std::thread(&Miner::JSEMine, this);
            }
            for (auto& th : t)
                if (th.joinable())
                    th.join();
        }
    }
}
```

which in turn get's called like this:

```
Miner m(threads);
m.Start();
```

Comment: It would be better of you to show hash calculating code instead of random emitting code (which does not seem to cause any trouble).

Comment: First of all; you should post a [MCVE]. Second; don't constantly recreate your generator - keep it alive and re-use it between invocations (re-creating *distributions* is fine; they don't hold state and are cheap, but generators *do* hold state and need to be seeded (*once*) and re-used - they are also expensive to construct).

Comment: OpenCL is good for vectorizable code (SIMD), and SHA256 is not exactly a vectorized computation.

Comment: @VTT I'll do that, hold on.

Comment: @JesperJuhl so re-using my RNG would make it faster?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch But Bitcoin also runs faster on a GPU right? then how would that go?

Comment: Bitcoin was designed to be vectorizable. SHA256 was not.

Comment: Note: using just time as a seed (regardless of resolution) is pretty bad and predictable to some degree. You want to mix other sources in there if you are going for a proper unpredictable seed (`std::random_device` would be a good choice - other stuff you might add (in addition to `random_device` if you feel like it) might be things like the CPUID of the users CPU, the current process ID, the current time since boot, the address of `main`, the value of a hash of your current environment variables, the MAC addr of your NIC, etc, etc - but don't just use time alone...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OclHashcat also pulls of a big hashrate in SHA256.

Comment: @JesperJuhl the seed doesn't have to be secure, just somewhat random :) (it won't be used for any security applications like storing passwords)

Answer (score 9):

CPUs have far better latency characteristics than GPUs. That is to say, CPUs can do **one** operation way, way WAAAAYYYY faster than a GPU can. That's not even taking into account the CPU -> Main RAM -> PCIe bus -> GDDR5 "Global" GPU -> GPU Registers -> "Global GPU" -> PCIe bus back -> Main RAM -> CPU round trip time (and I'm skipping a few steps here, like pinning and L1 Cache)

GPUs have better bandwidth characteristics than CPUs (provided that the dataset can fit inside of the GPU's limited local memory). GPUs can perform **Billions** of SHA256 hashes faster than a CPU can perform **billions** of SHA256 hashes.

Bitcoin requires millions, billions, or even trillions of hashes to achieve a competitive hash rate. Furthermore, computations can take place on the GPU without much collaboration with the CPU (removing the need for the slow round-trip through PCIe).

Its an issue of fundamental design. CPUs are designed to minimize latency, but GPUs are designed to maximize bandwidth. It seems like your problem is latency-bound (you're calculating too few SHA256 hashes for the GPU to be effective). 32 is... really really small in the scale we're talking about.

The AMD GCN architecture doesn't even perform full speed until you have at LEAST 64-work items, and arguably you really need 256 work items to maximize just one of the 44-compute units of say... a R9 290x.

I guess what I'm trying to say is: try it again with 11264 work items (or more), that's the number of work items that GPUs are designed to work with. Not 32. I got this number from 44-compute units on R9 290x * 4-Vector units per compute unit * 64-work items per vector unit.

Comment: Ah yes, I see.
So what it comes down to is that the GPU is being "starved" from work (in this case Random Numbers to hash)?
If so, then I don't understand how it comes that it get's starved.
The CPU can do 20kh/s by itself (so creating a random number and hashing it). then I would think that taking off the hashing load should increase the amount of random numbers it can generate.

Comment: There's numerous systems at play here. Before the CPU can talk to the GPU, it needs to "Pin" the memory its working on. Then it transfers the memory to main DDR3 (or DDR4), then the PCIe bus transfers the data to the GPU. In many cases, it might be faster to just SHA256 hash the thing on the CPU rather than wait for RAM to transfer the data to the GPU (let alone perform the calculation). You need to "batch up a lot of work" if you really want to take advantage of the GPU. Under normal conditions, its way faster to keep everything in CPU L1 cache and calculate.

Comment: ah yes I see.
Isn't there an easy way to generate enough work for the GPU?
Or will it simply take too long to be "profitable" anyways?

Comment: There's really no "easy" way. Each way you test will require profiling, testing and understanding. My first approach would be to generate all of the random numbers in a giant array (like have the CPU batch up 100MB+ of random numbers) and then have the GPU try to hash all of those. I don't know if it'd be faster however, you'd have to test it yourself. The CPU-only approach might still be faster because L1 cache of CPUs is blazingly fast... and any methodology using main-memory will naturally slow the CPU down significantly (including methods that talk to the GPU)

Comment: Ah okay.
Then I think Iĺl put the GPU stuff aside for now until I have a better understanding of it :)